# IBM BUS REST API Text Responce

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I created a Rest Service using IBM Integration BUS 10.0.0.5.
And using compute node I return simple json data **{"OTP":"123456"}** like on image.
But I need return a simple text like "**123456**" not json object.

**Which node or domain I must use? any sample code for this?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code

SET OutputRoot.BLOB.BLOB = CAST ('Test string' AS BLOB CCSID 1208);